# Variable as tag for xpath - bash script (html)

Tags: bash, xpath

I am currently trying to print set of data from the web page using xpath. I am having issues with looping over an array of tags as example below produces empty $element variables:

```
declare -a Elements=('//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[1]' '//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[2]');

COUNTER=1
for tag in "${Elements[@]}";
do
    element="$(curl -s http://mypage | xmllint --html --xpath '$tag' - 2>text.txt | tr -d 'a-z<>=""/')" \
    echo  ELEMENT $COUNTER : $element 
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

If I manually replace the '$tag' with xpath (.e.g having the following:

```
element="$(curl -s http://mypage | xmllint --html --xpath '//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[1]' - 2>text.txt | tr -d 'a-z<>=""/')" \
```

everything works perfectly. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I believe there is something wrong with syntax surrounding $tag, but I cannot see what exactly I'm doing incorrectly. Any nudge in right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
xmllint --html --xpath '$tag'
```

to

```
xmllint --html --xpath "$tag"
```

Its the *rule-of-thumb*, single-quotes do NOT expand variables in `bash`, you need to double-quote them.  Using a single quote around variable names, deprives `$` from doing variable interpolation.

Also a good read, [Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2016)

Comment: Thank you so much :) Great to know that!